# Keras Transfer learning on Inception ResnetV2 - Training stops in between because 'val_acc' didn't improve

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I was trying to test some celebrities images on `Inception ResnetV2` model for facial recognition using `KERAS`

Now, I tried to train with `epochs = 50`, but the training stopped at `Epoch 00027` because `validation_accuracy` didn't improve.

[image]

Now I understand this is a case of over-fitting on the data. I am not sure what parameters to tweak and what changes to make to avoid over-fitting. I might be doing something wrong.

Here are some important parts of code that'd be useful in identifying the problem

***The Model:***

```
model = applications.inception_resnet_v2.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3))
```

***Making top 5 layers `trainable = false`:***

```
for layer in model.layers[:5]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

***Adding custom layers:***

```
x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
```

***Model compile and other hyperparams:***

```
model_final.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

***Data Augmentation:***

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    fill_mode = "nearest",
    zoom_range = 0.3,
    width_shift_range = 0.3,
    height_shift_range=0.3,
    rotation_range=30)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    fill_mode = "nearest",
    zoom_range = 0.3,
    width_shift_range = 0.3,
    height_shift_range=0.3,
    rotation_range=30)
```

***Checkpointing and Early Stopping:***

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("custom_resnet.h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto')
```

I want to figure out why validation accuracy is stuck on such low.
Any help would be great 
Thanks :)

Comment: you should have actually used the code as text rather than the screenshot.

Comment: Hey, I was thinking the same. Give me a minute I'll edit :)

Comment: It can happen in any training process. It can have many reasons. I take a look at your code. I think the problem is from     `layer.trainable = False`
.It causes your model can not be trainable, so the training process will stop.

Comment: @PyMatFlow Yes. But is it a good idea to training my small dataset of 10 classes and 5 images per class on the Inception ResNetV2 from scratch (On all the layers) ?  I could remove custom layers too. Will it make some difference ?